# Div at the top, img in center and button in sub

Tags: html, css

I want to make a div like this

[image]

I used two `<div>` that contain two `<h2>` and must replace the top and bottom of the parent `<div>`.
Here is my code :

```css
.parent {
  background: #eae8db;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

.top {
  background-color:#d6d1b1; 
  height: 15%; 
  width: 100%; 
  position: absolute;
  top: -06%; 
  left: -03.7%; 
  line-height:100px; 
  vertical-align:middle;
}

h2{ text-align: center;}

.center {
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 }

.bottom{
  background-color:#24bfd1;
  height: 5%; 
  width: 100%; 
  position: absolute;
  bottom : 60%;
  left: -03.7%; 
  line-height:100px; 
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="parent" >
    <div class="top">
      <h2>E-book</h2>
    </div>
    <img class="center" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    <div class="bottom">
      <h2>Voir</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Link to [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hxzg71L4/)

Someone can help me to adapt it please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just made some changes in your CSS, replace it should help :

```
.parent {
  background: #eae8db;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  height: 300px;
  position:relative;
}

.top {
  background-color:#d6d1b1; 
  height: 15%; 
  width: 100%; 
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.bottom{
  background-color:#24bfd1;
  height: 12%; 
  width: 100%; 
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a fiddle based on your DOM: 
https://jsfiddle.net/xy0zqsnt/1/

I also tried to reuse your css classes, but I threw out some stuff, which didn't make sense to me. There is still room for improvement, but I hope you are able to recognize the changes in the css.

The main point is the use of `display:flex` in the `.parent` css class. Flexbox helps a lot for layout tasks like this, make sure to check it out (e.g.: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ - but there are many resources out there!)

---

HTML

```
 <div class="parent" >
    <div class="top">
      <h2>E-book</h2>
    </div>
    <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    <div class="bottom">
      <h2>Voir</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
h2{ text-align: center;}

.parent {
  background: #eae8db;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 300px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.top {
  background-color:#d6d1b1; 
  width: 100%; 
}

.bottom{
  background-color:#24bfd1;
  width: 100%; 
}

.image{
  margin: 1em;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and advice

Answer (score 0):

```
Solution: ->

No need to use absolute position for this layout...

Here is the solution: ->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="parent" >
    <div class="top">
      <h2>E-book</h2>
    </div>
    <p>
    <img class="center" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    </p>
    <div class="bottom">
      <h2>Voir</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>


CSS part-> 

.parent {
     background: #eae8db;
     margin: 20px;
}

.top {
  background-color:#d6d1b1; 
  padding: 20px;

}
p{
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
h2{ text-align: center;}


.bottom{
  background-color:#24bfd1;
  padding: 10px;
}
```